# How do I calculate the correlation with non linear, non monotonically data?

Tags: correlation

I have the following data:

[image]
[image]

I need to calculate the correlation between this data. How do I go about this? I can't use product-moment correlation or rank correlation coefficient as my data is neither linear nor monotonically.

I have found Lowess, but this seems to be for regression, not correlation. If Lowess is the answer, I am not sure how to implement this into my R script.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I'm sorry, could you clarify why exactly you couldn't calculate correlation? You mention it's non-linear, and non-monotonic. To be honest, neither of those are super obvious to me. The lines seem heavily skewed by a few outliers. At first glance, my first thought is "there is barely any kind of relationship here". How do you know it's non-linear and non-monotonic, as opposed to "just random/no-relationship-at-all"?

Comment: The quick answer is that you just calculate the correlations, and if those numbers indicate little correlation, then that's consistent with the graphs (I'm not so sure that I agree with this, but that's your interpretation of the graphs, so we will go with that). That you considered calculating correlation and did not want to go with such an approach makes me think you have a different question than correlation. In particular, what exactly do you mean by "correlation"?

Comment: What do you really want to find out from your data? It might be correlation is not a good help for that ... tell us **why** you want a correlation here!

Comment: Okay, I think I understood my problem. I basically simply forgot the possibility of not having a correlation. It makes way more sense that there is no correlation. Thank you all for helping out! :)